# Is the usage of auxiliary verb "is" correct in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs, present-simple

> Agency **is** a system integrator of innovation processes in the region,
>   **manages** infrastructure projects of innovation development, **coordinates**
>   the implementation of NTI roadmaps (National technology initiative),
>   **acts** as the Representative Office of the Fund (Federal) for Assistance
>   to Small Innovative Enterprises, acts as a specialized organization
>   for the management of territorial innovation clusters.

I came across this sentence, and it seems to me that the usage of the auxiliary verb "is" in the first part is incorrect in combination with the other verbs presented. Is it ok, if only one of the several verbs that describe the subject is auxiliary? Thank you!

Comment: What else would you put there? ***Is*** is the singular form in present tense, as are all the other bolded verbs in that passage. They all agree, even if you don't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i just was not sure it is a correct sentence structure

Comment: It may feel strange to you because **is** is a copula, not an ordinary verb like the rest. Also because the sentence is not really well written. I personally would make the first clause a separate sentence, then use the dummy subject ***it*** to head the second sentence: "It manages ..., coordinates ..., acts ...."

Comment: So despite the formal correctness of this sentence, it sounds not natural and you would not advise to use similar structure in the formal text, right?

Comment: It doesn't exactly sound *un*natural, just long and rambling and infelicitous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**
It’s fine: *is* acts as a copula (“linking verb”) heading its clause and parallels *manages*, *coordinates* and *acts*.

**AUXILIARIES**
I think you may be confused by the conflict between traditional and contemporary use of the technical term “auxiliary verb”.

In traditional English grammars *auxiliary* designated a specific syntactic role: a verb acting in support of a *principal* or "main" verb in a construction to express tense or mood:

> A Notional verb [...] is one used as a Principal verb to express a full meaning of its own:—
>
> > (1) He *has* ten horses.
>
> Here *has* is a Transitive verb, and is used to express the notion of “possession.” Now look at the following:—
>
> > (2) He *has* been ill to-day.
>
> Here *has* is [...] merely a *tense-forming*, that is, an Auxiliary verb. It has, for the time being, *discarded its proper sense* of “possession,” in order to *help the verb “be” to form a Present Perfect tense. It is not notional, but merely modifies the notion expressed by “be.”
>   —Nesfield, *English Grammar Past and Present*, 1920

In traditional English grammar, then, *HAVE* and *BE* might act as **either** "auxiliary" **or** "principal" verbs at different times, depending on context.

In contemporary English, however, *auxiliary* is a category designating verbs  which **may** play certain syntactic roles, the so-called 
“NICE” properties **N**egation, **I**nversion, **C**ode, **E**mphasis (see [this](https://www.englishpractice.com/grammar/properties-auxiliary-verbs/)). For contemporary grammarians *HAVE* and *BE*, which exhibit these properties, are regarded as “auxiliary verbs” in **all** contexts.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation, it's very useful! But would it be appropriate to use this kind of structure in a formal text?

Comment: @airko Absolutely. *HAVE* and *BE* are both frequently used as what traditional grammar called "principal" verbs: *I **have** a pencil; it **is** red*. So in fact may the auxiliary *WILL*; in this sentence it is used as both: *I will will my estate to my grandchildren*.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree. While it's clear that the original sentence is attempting to use a parallel structure coordinating *is*, *manages*, *coordinates*, and *acts*, in my   opinion the resulting English is poor.  The problem is what the OP points to: the attempt to parallel the active lexical verbs *manages*, *coordinates* and *acts* with the copula auxiliary verb *is*. Compare a simpler sentence:

> Bill buys grain, sells bread and earns a profit. (good)
>   
>  * Bill seems happy, sells bread and earns a profit. (dubious)

The original sentence would be much better by breaking the infelicitous parallel, for example by using 'which':

> Agency is a system integrator of innovation processes in the region, **which** manages infrastructure projects of innovation development, coordinates the implementation of NTI roadmaps (National technology initiative), acts as the Representative Office of the Fund (Federal) for Assistance to Small Innovative Enterprises, **and** acts as a specialized organization for the management of territorial innovation clusters.